Trusted types in Angular
I am trying to enable trusted types in Angular. Adding the CSP header is not a problem but once I try to add a custom policy I get the following error.
If I look at MDN they say the property does exist but is not supported in all browsers.

✘ [ERROR] TS2339: Property 'trustedTypes' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/main.ts:13:29:
      13 │       let sanatizer = window.trustedTypes.createPolicy('my-policy', {


You can reproduce it with opening Angular playground and adding the test method to the component.
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {bootstrapApplication} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    Hello world!
  `,
})
export class PlaygroundComponent {
  public test() : void {
    let sanatizer = window.trustedTypes.createPolicy('my-policy', {

    ));
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(PlaygroundComponent);

What am I missing?

If a property exists in a browser, it does not necessarily mean that TypeScript provides the typings for it, especially for features which are not supported in all major browsers. For this particular typings you can track the following GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30024

It seems like a new feature and will be added in the Window type in future.

This is marked as below in MDN.
Limited availability

This feature is not Baseline because it does not work in some of the most widely-used browsers.


If you must use it, you have to defined a custom type.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export type WindowExtended = (Window & typeof globalThis & {trustedTypes: any });

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  public test() : void {
    let sanatizer = (window as WindowExtended).trustedTypes.createPolicy('my-policy', {
      
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

The simplest way is to just mark window as any.
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  public test(): void {
    let sanatizer = (window as any).trustedTypes.createPolicy(
      'my-policy',
      {}
    );
  }
}


TypeScript doesn't include the typings for trusted types yet, as it's a functionality which is currently only available in Chrome (as you can read in the MDN doc you linked). You can install the typings from Definitely Typed via the @types/trusted-types npm package.
